# C# PushSharp Memory Leak

Tags: c#, pushsharp

I found a problem using PushSharp and I hope you bring me some light. I'm using it in a console c# application doing a while(true) waiting for fetching new push notifications to send, each time I've got new notifications in the backend I send a batch.

I'm talking in fact about two problems:

**1. If I use this way, after a device receives some notifications (sometimes one, two or three) It stops suddenly getting new ones. I note that this notifications are sent different days, Im not talking one followed by the other.**

**Ex 1.**

```
    public static PushBroker pushBroker;
    public static List<PushNotificationEnt> notificationsQueuedToBeSent = new List<PushNotificationEnt>();
    public static byte[] appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["certificate_path"]);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        pushBroker = new PushBroker();
        pushBroker.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
        pushBroker.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(bool.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["isProduction"]), appleCert, "xxxxxxxxxxx"));



        DateTime timeController = DateTime.Now;
        int iteratorIdleController = 0;
        int cycleSeconds = int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["cycle_seconds"]);


        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                iteratorIdleController++;
                if ((DateTime.Now - timeController).TotalSeconds >= cycleSeconds)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Starting iteration");
                    timeController = DateTime.Now;
                    SendPushNotifications();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excp)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error- " + excp.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

**2. If I create a new PushBroker each time the loop starts, the console app starts leaking RAM memory until this is over.**

**Ex 2.**

```
    public static PushBroker pushBroker;
    public static List<PushNotificationEnt> notificationsQueuedToBeSent = new List<PushNotificationEnt>();
    public static byte[] appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["certificate_path"]);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime timeController = DateTime.Now;
        int iteratorIdleController = 0;
        int cycleSeconds = int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["cycle_seconds"]);


        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                pushBroker = new PushBroker();
                pushBroker.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
                pushBroker.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(bool.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["isProduction"]), appleCert, "xxxxxx"));


                iteratorIdleController++;
                if ((DateTime.Now - timeController).TotalSeconds >= cycleSeconds)
                {
                    PushNotificationsSender pushNotificationsSender = new PushNotificationsSender(appleCert);

                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Starting iteration");
                    timeController = DateTime.Now;
                    SendPushNotifications();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excp)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error- " + excp.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something? any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I know this is old, but I think there's a couple things to note. One is that you don't release the event. The garbage collector might not have run. Try explicitly calling GC.Collect() to see if the RAM really is increasing, or use a using statement with the PushBroker. Or try releasing the event.

Comment: Also, did you call StopAllServices()? If you do call it, it will deregister the service and it won't work after that, which is why the first one probably quit on you. If you don't call StopAllServices(), the second one should overwrite your object and it's likely that the old PushBroker might not send its notifications. It might still be sending them because the garbage collector doesn't kill it immediately (i.e. the object and its service are still hanging around in memory). GC.Collect() should check this as well. I think your SendPushNotifications code is very relevant here.